# Application framework for Java desktop applications?

Tags: java, swing, spring, frameworks

I'm currently using a custom framework to build Java Swing applications which have event monitoring over a network. I'd like to replace our custom networking layer with something like JMS but our framework is tightly coupled to its current implementation.

This lead me to search for existing application frameworks which may already have the capabilities we need. Spring was one of the frameworks I considered since it appears to be one of the more lightweight solutions available. We are currently using Guice for our DI needs but I see I can get similar features from the Spring container as well.

Would Spring be a good fit for building Java Swing applications or should I be considering other application frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring to do this, take a look at the following articles for an idea of how to use it to build Swing applications:

http://java.dzone.com/news/spring-enabling-decoupled-swin

Comment: Good article on wiring swing components but I don't think it is very practical in complex GUIs (i.e. hard to maintain). We usually only wire our MVC triads and use GUI building tools like SwingDesigner for our views.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is the best framework to do this.

We're using Spring in a huge energy trading application on client (Swing) as well middle tier side. It deserves all the prising.